# First row Horizontal Recyclerview with Vertical RecyclerView in android

Tags: android, header, android-recyclerview

I want to use horizontal recycler with vertical recycler together like google play store but in my app only the first row like image below. I used scrollview but it not correct like I want when we have a lot of data and pagination. And it also has header section for horizontal and vertical recycler and the horizontal recycler header section will change when vertical header section scroll to it the same to TitleSection of UiTableView in iOS. 
Thank you!

[image]

Comment: create 2 viewholder class one for vertical and another for horizontal scrolling and in getItemViewType(int position) of your adapter.. set positions accordingly

Comment: Have you got example code?

Answer (score 1):

1. Use `NestedScrollView` as container of `RecyclerViews`.
2. Set `LinearLayoutManager` to `recycler_view_horizontal` with `Horizontal` orientation.
3. set `LinearLayoutManager` to `recycler_view_vertical` with `Vertical` orientation.
4. Use `RecyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false)` to `RecyclerView` for smooth scrolling.

**Design your layout structure as below:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/layout_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
            app:titleTextColor="@android:color/white"
            app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp">
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/layout_scorll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/header1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
                android:paddingBottom="8dp"
                android:paddingTop="8dp"
                android:text="Horizontal Recycler Header"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recycler_view_horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/header2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
                android:paddingBottom="8dp"
                android:paddingTop="8dp"
                android:text="Vertical Recycler Header"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recycler_view_vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**In your Activtiy:**

```
mRecyclerViewHorizontal.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
mRecyclerViewVertical.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);

mRecyclerViewHorizontal.setHasFixedSize(false);
mRecyclerViewVertical.setHasFixedSize(false);
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I already set nestedScrollingEnabled = "false" but It's not smooth like we want.

Comment: I want to use the horizontal recyclerview inside the first row of vertical vertical recyclerview so when I scroll the horizontal recyclerview will disappear. If we use that code above mean that we fixed recyclerview in vertical and horizontal.

Comment: As we are using `NestedScrollView` and added two `RecyclerView` inside it. So if we scroll, the both horizontal and vertical RecyclerView will scroll and will behave as normal list. As a result horizontal `RecyclerView` will disappear first then other rows of vertical  `RecyclerView`. I guess `Google play store` also used this technique. I have used it in so many apps and its working properly. Thank you~

Answer (score 0):

1. In this case, use one recycler view for vertical items.
2. For top horizontal (recycler view or scroll view or any view), add a header in vertical recycler view.
3. You need to use a custom adapter to add header and you can add multiple headers as of your need.
4. Don't forget to increase the size of the list.

   ```
     @Override
     public int getItemCount() {
     // if one header added
     return list.size() + 1;
     }
   ```